# Hi, at startup cmd\design javafx\cmd eclipse my file isn't delete and isn't copy

Tags: java, javafx, cmd

My program makes a copy of itself and delete itself. If im runing it without cmd\javafx then everything is coping and deleting, but if with cmd\javafx, then it is ceases coping and deleting. 
Why it happens? And how can I get around this trap.
And yes, if copies and delet any other fiel, then all do
Code (copy):

```
FileChannel source = new FileInputStream(new File(jarLocate)).getChannel();
    FileChannel dest = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\"+jarName)).getChannel();
  try {
    source.transferTo(0, source.size(), dest);
  } finally {
    source.close();
    dest.close();
  }
```

Code(delet):

```
 File file = new File(rd);
           if (file.delete()) {
               System.out.println(" Файл "+rd+" успешно удалён!");
           } else {
               System.out.println(" Файл "+rd+" не существует.");
           }
```

Comment: Might be due to a file lock on the jar that you are running...

Comment: if you're talking about finaly, then I removed it, nothing happened. Or I don’t understand what kind of lock

Comment: The OS, or maybe CMD, could be holding a lock on the JAR file. In which case you should be getting an error; what is that error?

Comment: The joke is that there is no error, it doesn't throw any errors, and the program doesn't stop

Answer (score 0):

This is just a theory, but what might be happening is that when you run JavaFX, is that the JavaFX places a "file lock" on the JAR file, because it "might" need resources from the JAR(images, icons, translation files). In order to prevent the JAR from becoming manipulated it claims an exclusive file lock on the JAR whilst the program is executing, so no undefined behavior/exceptions will occur.

When you run in console, it doesn't need to access any resources from the JAR, so a file lock isn't warranted to guarantee safe running, as it runs 100% from memory without(as far as the default libraries are concerned) a dependency on resources within the JAR.

Comment: ok, but why, when im closing javafx it all the same isn't deleting the file (copied file). And how can i solve this problem?

Comment: @ScpaceHouse First of all, it's bad to delete the file you're running the program from. You open yourself to undefined behavior on so many levels if something isn't loaded in memory and still needs to be loaded from the JAR file. Why do you wish to do this anyway?

Comment: im want deleting copy file. 
I dont want to delete the file from which my code works. only deleting copy file

Comment: Ahhh, now I get it. Are you perhaps trying to delete the file too soon, that the writing hasn't completed and the filestream is still open? Can you post a complete minimal example of the malfunctioning code?

Comment: It seems that I closed all the streams, but the strange thing is that without a console and design everything works.`Files.walk(Paths.get("D:\\"), FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)
.map(Path::toFile)
.forEach(f -> {...}); String rd = null; try( FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\readme32.txt"))
{int c;
while((c=reader.read())!=-1){
rd=rd+(char)c;
System.out.print((char)c);  
}  
reader.close(); 
File file = new File(rd);
file.delete();
}
catch(IOException ex){
System.out.println(ex.getMessage());} `